# Pandas how to use initially generated column names without renaming them

Tags: python, pandas

I was curious that is any way we can use these initially generated `column names` by `Pandas` while reading a `csv/Text` files like as follows

```
df = pd.read_csv("some_text_file.txt", header = None)
```

which will produce something like

```
     0         1         2

0   data1    data2     data3  
1  r2 data1  r2 data2     r2 data3
```

When we used `header = None` it generated some `column names as = 0  1  2` by default.

When I try to access them like

```
-->    df['0'] = sometask
```

It throws error

> raise KeyError(key) from err
> KeyError: '0'

Aren't they column names at all?. I've seen some people calling them as `Levels`. Like

```
level0 - column 0
level1 - column 1
level2 - column 2
```

I've also tried

```
-->    df[level0] = sometask
```

it throws an error:

> NameError: name 'level0' is not definedNameError: name 'level0' is not defined

I know we have to rename the column names and use them like

```
df.columns =['col1','col2'.....]
```

But, wondering there is any way we can these `pandas` generated `column names` without renaming them as shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), you can pass a list to the `names` parameter. E.g.:

```
df = pd.read_csv('some_text_file.txt', header=None, 
                 names=[f'col_{i}' for i in range(1,4)])

print(df)

      col_1     col_2     col_3
0     data1     data2     data3
1  r2 data1  r2 data2  r2 data3
```

Note that the list of `names` cannot contain any duplicates (e.g. `['col', 'col', 'col2']` will cause an error).

---

The default col "names" `0,1,2` etc. are integers, rather than strings. You can check this as follows:

```
print(df.columns)

Int64Index([0, 1, 2], dtype='int64')
```

E.g. to access column `0`, you should use `df[0]` or `df.loc[:,0]`, not `df['0']` etc.

Comment: Understood...the normaly way to call coloumn is `df['some_nbame']` ....So I was in state that these `0,1,2,3` ... are also column names...so should be used like `df['0']`  ....Thanks for the detail explination!!

Comment: You're welcome. Just to be sure, `0,1,2,3` *are* column names, they are just not strings. So, the misunderstanding consists of the assumption that column names are always `strings`. E.g. you could also use a float for a column name (not that I would advise you to do so...). E.g. use `df = df.rename(columns={'col_1':0.25})`, and then check the type: `print(type(df.columns[0]))`. This will return: `<class 'float'>`. Even a boolean (e.g. `True`) will work, but that seems a particularly bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the columns is, by default, a number. Hence, when trying to access `df['0']`, you get a `KeyError`, but if you use `df[0]`, you will get the first column.

Comment: How did I missed that!!